# Replace string if it contains two partial strings

Tags: r

I would like to replace a set of strings (`d`) with a string `SELF EMPLOYED`, if both words `SELF` and `EMPLOYED` were found in the string.

```
d <- c("SELF EMPLOYED-EMPLOYED", "SELF- EMPLOYED", "MYSELF
SELF-EMPLOYED AND BARNARD COLLEGE", "SELF EMPLOYED BUSINESS", "CENTER FOR SELF-ANALYSIS INCORPORATED")
```

This does not seem to work:

```
d[grepl("SELF" & "EMPLOYED", d, ignore.case=FALSE)] <- "SELF EMPLOYED"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in "SELF" & "EMPLOYED" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Could you please kindly shed some light on how I am supposed to code this?

Comment: `d[grepl("SELF.*?EMPLOYED", d, ignore.case=FALSE)] <- "SELF EMPLOYED"`?

Comment: Thats amazing. It works! Thanks a lot Psidom!

Comment: Actually, at this stage, can I also ask, how would the code look like if we were to brand 'Self Employed' anyone who has EITHER 'Self' OR 'Employed' written in their string?

Comment: Replace the pattern with *self|employed*

Comment: awesome, thanks. If we are looking for a string 'investor', but we do not want 'investor relations', how would you formulate this rule?